# i cant make sense of this weirdly deterministic result caused by pthreads

Tags: c, pthreads

i wrote this code down below and before you set me on fire, yes i know that 2 threads shouldnt access the same global variable the way i've set it up, this is just testing to see what kind of random results it would come up with.
So, the program takes 2 args, and adds all the numbers up to it to a global sum (or subtracts if it is negative). I thought i would give it the same number, 1 positive and 1 negative, and see the random result caused by desync between the threads but, if i give 10.000 and -10.000 it runs "correctly" and prints that the sum is 0, but if i give 100.000 and -100.000 (or any bigger multiple of 10) it just prints the result that it would print if i gave it 100.000 and 0 (you can try it with (100.000 and -100.000) and (100.000 and 0), both give 5000050000 as the result) , so, as if only 1 of the threads ever worked.
Could anyone help me make sense of it? What is causing this?

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <pthread.h>

#define NUM_THREADS 2

long long sum = 0;

void* sumAll(void *incr){
    long long i;
    long long arg=atoll((char*)incr);
    printf("arg is %lld\n",arg);
    if(arg>0){
        //printf("1arg is %d\n",arg);
        for(i=0; i<=arg; i++){
            //printf("sum incremented to %lld\n",sum);
            sum+=i;
        }
    }
    else
    {
        for(i=0; i>=arg; i--){
            //printf("sum decremented to %lld\n",sum);
            sum+=i;
        }
    }
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    pthread_t threads[NUM_THREADS];

    pthread_create(&threads[0],NULL,sumAll,(void *)argv[1]);
    pthread_create(&threads[1],NULL,sumAll,(void *)argv[2]);

    pthread_join(threads[0],NULL);
    pthread_join(threads[1],NULL);

    printf("sum final %lld\n",sum);
    
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: What operating system are you using?

Comment: *"yes i know that 2 threads shouldnt access the same global variable"* - And that's the reason

Comment: @user3386109 im on linux, pop_os 20.10, ryzen 7 1700 16gb ram (if it matters)

Comment: @klutt maybe, but isnt this a weirdly specific result? shouldnt it be almost completely random?

Comment: The first sentence of your question _is_ your _answer_. You will get _random_ results because you have a race condition between your threads for access to the global `sum`. Don't _try_ to make sense of it, because one can't.

Comment: I think linux has a time slice of 100 msec. So my guess is that with 10.000 the first thread finishes before the second thread is allowed to run. In other words, the threads **aren't** accessing the same variable at the same time. With 100.000, the threads are sharing the variable in theory, but really the threads use their own versions of the variable. The last thread to finish determines the result.

Comment: You're assuming an access sequence like: `A fetch sum; A increment; A store sum;  B fetch sum; B decrement; B store sum`. But, you could get: `A fetch sum; B fetch sum; A increment; A store sum;  B decrement; B store sum` which blows away A's stored value. Many other things are possible ;-)

Comment: @CraigEstey i know, but the thing is the result wasnt random, it was *weirdly deterministic*, thats why im trying to make a bit of sense out of it

Comment: @user3386109 this makes more sense yeah, except for one point, why would each of the threads use "their own version of the variable"? arent they accessing the same memory location?

Comment: @CraigEstey i know, and that would give me a random result somewhere in the middle of 0 and one of the other sums, but here i have many accesses to the same variable in a for loop, both fol loops should run in parallel each changing the `sum` each time. The only way i could get the same result every time is if `sum` was "instantiated" for each of the threads, and the thread that finishes last puts the actual result into `sum`

Comment: Depends on what optimizations the compiler performed. At the highest level of optimization, the loop would be completely optimized out, and the code would just write the final answer to the memory. At a lower level of optimization, `sum` might be computed in a register, and then written to memory at the end of the loop. With no optimization, the code would still put the `sum` and `i` into registers, then perform the addition, and write the result to memory. Between reading and writing, the processor is using its own version of the variable.

Comment: @user3386109 ohh yeah i forgot that optimization might be interfering with it, i will try it again without optimizations and test around, thanks!

Comment: @user3386109 Yup! that was it, i get random results now just i expected, thanks! if you want you can repost it as an actual answer and i will mark it as correct, not sure how this works this is my first question ^^

Comment: _both for loops should run in parallel each changing the sum each time._ What if that were _not_ the case [which it isn't necessarily]? Referring to my "access sequence" comment, A is sequential against A [and B against B], repeating for the length of the loop. But, _any_ interspersal of operations between A and B are possible on an instruction by instruction basis. You might get 1000 A ops, then 2 B ops, then 37 A ops, and 19 B ops

Comment: @user3386109 A 100ms time slice is a rescheduling rate of 10 times / sec. In the old days, it was 10ms (100/sec). But, x86 has been 1ms (1000/sec) for a while now. And, modern schedulers can interrupt almost on a ns-by-ns basis. That is, has an event queue and schdules a wakeup when the next timer event would expire (supports fine-grained `nanosleep`)

Answer (score 2):

I actually had an error with 10000. Here is the run:

```
$ ./a.out 10000 -10000
arg is -10000
arg is 10000
sum final 9996198
```

> yes i know that 2 threads shouldnt access the same global variable the way i've set it up

That's the very reason of your problem. You're experiencing *race conditions*. In order to solve it, use a lock.

```
// Declare a global lock
pthread_mutex_t lock;

// Surround the sum assignments with lock and unlock

void* sumAll(void *incr){
    // Like before
        pthread_mutex_lock(&lock);
        sum+=i;
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&lock);
```

The most likely reason that your program "works" for lower numbers is that the threads are not running at the same time. The first finishes before the second start.

Comment: yeah thats what i was expecting! i wanted incorrect results like `9996198`! but thats not what i got, my result when using 100.000 and -100.000 is the exact same with when i use 100.000 and 0, which tells me that probably one of the threads isnt working, or maybe doesnt even start